# google maps drag ajax not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get features like http://www.yelp.com/ where when user drags a map it will call ajax and collect lat, lng and populate maps markers.

Here is some sample code I tried

```
  function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 12,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.1594, -80.7614),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mymap-screenwrap'), mapOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', getPinsToMapBound);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', getPinsToMapBound);

    var start =(document.getElementById('cr-start-point'));

    var end=(document.getElementById('cr-end-point'));

    var autocompleteA = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(start);

    var autocompleteB = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(end);               

    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    directionsDisplay.setOptions( { suppressMarkers: true } );

    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel-direction-content'));
    if(start.value != '') {
      routehelper();
    }

  }

  function getPinsToMapBound(ev) {
    var ids;
    if(ids = $$('.mymaps_topmenu a.pressed').get('id')) {
      var bounds = map.getBounds();
      var ne = [bounds.getNorthEast().lat(), bounds.getNorthEast().lng()];
      var sw = [bounds.getSouthWest().lat(), bounds.getSouthWest().lng()];
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/rvillage/maps/get-data-within-lat-lng',
        data: {bounds : bounds, ne : ne, sw : sw, format : 'json'},
        dataType: 'json'
      }).done(function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
  }
```

Now problem is the ajax part doesn't work when I drag map it throws an error - **TypeError: this is undefined
https://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/16/3/%7Bmain,places%7D.js
Line 28**. If I turn off the ajax it doesn't throw errors. Can anyone point me where I am wrong ? **I am using both mootools & jQuery in combination & there is no error when I comment ajax part & I have used mootools delay to delay this function but not worked**. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I can't create jsfiddle because separating this part of js will be tough but if you want I can give you url of the site thanks

Comment: I dont think i would have access to your site as i have firewall issues. jsfiddle is something i can compromise. anyway, you dont have to load your complete code there, just relevant code which showcases your problem would be sufficient

Comment: @dreamweiver this code is responsible for whole execution break down & generates js exception. If you need credentials I can provide you that. thanks

Comment: Yeah provide me with the required credentials, i`ll try

Comment: http://dev.rvillage.com/login email-rana@technobd.com pass-rana123 & than go to http://dev.rvillage.com/explore and drag you will get the error I still can't figure it out seeing yelp system but they have minified there js so having hard time to find how they are calling ajax when map drags. If you can figure out how yelp system is calling ajax & tell me that will be also great. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly mistake I was adding **`bounce`** value to ajax data which was creating problem because when it was calling **`toString`** for **`bounce`** value the error was occurring **`bounce`** value wasn't necessary

```
  function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 12,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.1594, -80.7614),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mymap-screenwrap'), mapOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', getPinsToMapBound);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', getPinsToMapBound);

    var start =(document.getElementById('cr-start-point'));

    var end=(document.getElementById('cr-end-point'));

    var autocompleteA = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(start);

    var autocompleteB = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(end);               

    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    directionsDisplay.setOptions( { suppressMarkers: true } );

    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel-direction-content'));
    if(start.value != '') {
      routehelper();
    }

  }

  function getPinsToMapBound(ev) {
    var ids;
    if(ids = $$('.mymaps_topmenu a.pressed').get('id')) {
      var bounds = map.getBounds();
      var ne = [bounds.getNorthEast().lat(), bounds.getNorthEast().lng()];
      var sw = [bounds.getSouthWest().lat(), bounds.getSouthWest().lng()];
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/rvillage/maps/get-data-within-lat-lng',
        data: {ids : ids, ne : ne, sw : sw, format : 'json'},//removed bounds as it wasn't needed
        dataType: 'json'
      }).done(function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
  }
```